# Where did my transfer button go in Pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

The option or button to transfer Pokemon's to the professor has disappeared? Droid Phone. Is there a limit of transfers?

Answer (score 0):

If you select a Pokemon there is a button with 3 lines in the lower right corner. If you press that you have the option to transfer your Pokemon.

Note that you can't transfer your Pokemon if the Pokemon is a favorite.